# Flutter prevent building a new widget if already in tree

Tags: flutter, tree, duplicates, widget

For some reason, the Build method is called twice which results in two MainContent widgets being created. The problem is that in one of my widgets a Listener displays messages to the user according to certain actions. Because Maincontent is duplicated, messages are displayed twice.

[widget tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4bYF.png)

How to prevent the MainContent widget from being duplicated?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Bloc.observer = ProductBlocObserver();
  var productStorage = ProductStorage();
  await productStorage.products().then((localProducts) async {

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool('isMember', false);
    await prefs.setBool('membershipError', false);
    await prefs.setBool('firstOpen', true);
    await prefs.setString('memberFirstName', '');
    await prefs.setString('token', '');

    runApp(App(list: localProducts));

  });
}
```

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  List<LocalProductEntity> list;
  App({Key? key, required this.list}) : super(key: key) {
    list = list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return BlocProvider <ListBloc>(
      create: (_) => ListBloc(list: list),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
        title: constants.appTitle,
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
            primary: Color(ColorsLNC.green5),
            secondary: Color(ColorsLNC.green1),
          ),
        ),
        home: BlocPage()
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class BlocPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  late Future<bool> isMember;
  late Future<bool> membershipError;
  late Future<bool> firstOpen;
  late Future<String> memberFirstName;
  late Future<String> token;
  late BuildContext context;

  BlocPage({super.key});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    isMember = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
      return prefs.getBool('isMember') ?? false;
    });
    membershipError = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
      return prefs.getBool('membershipError') ?? false;
    });
    firstOpen = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
      return prefs.getBool('firstOpen') ?? false;
    });
    memberFirstName = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
      return prefs.getString('memberFirstName') ?? '';
    });
    token = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
      return prefs.getString('token') ?? '';
    });

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: membershipFlow(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            default:
              return snapshot.data;
          }
        });
  }

  Future<Widget> membershipFlow() async {
    if (await isMember == true && await membershipError == false) {
      return SplashPage(
        mainContext : context,
        goToPage: MainContent(),
        text: await memberFirstName,
        duration: 2,
      );
    } else if (await isMember == false && await membershipError == false) {
      return const MembershipForm();
    } else if (await isMember == false && await membershipError == true) {
      return ErrorPage(text: Babel.translate(key: 'E_WRONG_MEMBERSHIP'));
    } else {
      return ErrorPage(text: Babel.translate(key: 'E_UNEXPECTED'));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `const` with both constructor and while using it.

For example
`const BlocPage({super.key})`  and `const BlocPage()`.

You code has different issue tough. You could refactor your code like this and build won't be called repeatedly.

```dart
class BlocPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlocPage({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: membershipFlow(context),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            default:
              return snapshot.data;
          }
        });
  }

  Future<Widget> membershipFlow(BuildContext context) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final isMember = prefs.getBool('isMember') ?? false;
    final membershipError = prefs.getBool('membershipError') ?? false;
    final firstOpen = prefs.getBool('firstOpen') ?? false;
    final memberFirstName = prefs.getString('memberFirstName') ?? '';
    final token = prefs.getString('token') ?? '';

    if (isMember == true && membershipError == false) {
      return SplashPage(
        mainContext : context,
        goToPage: MainContent(),
        text: memberFirstName,
        duration: 2,
      );
    } else if (isMember == false && membershipError == false) {
      return const MembershipForm();
    } else if (isMember == false && membershipError == true) {
      return ErrorPage(text: Babel.translate(key: 'E_WRONG_MEMBERSHIP'));
    } else {
      return ErrorPage(text: Babel.translate(key: 'E_UNEXPECTED'));
    }
  }
}
```